# DevExpress Gridview with splitter not shows properly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, devexpress

I made a web application from dev express templates and changed the gridview to be rendered from splitter like this(change in file Views/Home/Index if you wnt to try):

```
@model System.Collections.IEnumerable

@Html.DevExpress().Splitter(settings =>
{
    settings.Name = "testsSplitter";
    settings.FullscreenMode = true;
    settings.AllowResize = true;
    settings.Orientation = System.Web.UI.WebControls.Orientation.Horizontal;
    settings.Panes.Add(pane =>
    {
        pane.ScrollBars = System.Web.UI.WebControls.ScrollBars.Auto;
        pane.SetContent(() =>
        {

            ViewContext.Writer.Write(Html.Partial("GridViewPartialView", Model));

        });


    });
}).GetHtml()
```

and now in internet explorer(my version is 9) the home page look like this:

[image]

As you can see the header become very big.

I have a real web application thet have the same problem and my client not love it...
Someone know how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that two splitter have the "Full screen mode" the splitter of the layout and my new splitter and this is not recommended! see dev express answer: [Dev express team answer](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q559874#answer-e5ea2d5d-745f-11e3-bedb-bced991fa6fd)